# How many requests per seconds

Tags: api, request, multiversx

We use the REST API to check the last 20 transactions for a specific user

What is the max number of requests per seconds we can make using the Elrond REST API ?

Comment: You can always run your own node with unlimited API request rate. It is not very difficult.

Answer (score 1):

The rate limits for the official api aren't known as far as I'm aware.

If you plan to have a lot of requests each second you might want to consider setting up your own [observer squad](https://docs.elrond.com/integrators/observing-squad/) and [api](https://github.com/ElrondNetwork/api.elrond.com) so you can be independent from the elrond infrastructure. This not only gives you greater control over the response times (and downtimes), but you will also reduce the load on the official servers so others won't be affected by the amount of requests you make.